# How to update a column of type text for all customers based on a condition in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a customer model and controller in my rails application. In my customers listing index page I am displaying all customers with search filter options to display customers according to their purchase type (Sale, Lease, Trial).

```
@customers = Customer.where(customer_type: ["Sale","Lease","Trail"]).count
```

If the `count > 0` I want to update their `customer_type` **field to its capitalized form** (Sale -> SALE , Lease -> LEASE, Trail -> TRAIL) for all customers in the `@customers` collection .

How to achieve it in a most optimised way ?

Comment: Please tag the correct Rails version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `upcase` method of ruby, while looping the customers.

```
@customers = Customer.where(customer_type: ["Sale","Lease","Trail"])

@customers.each do |customer|
    customer_type = customer.customer_type.upcase
  customer.update_attribute(:customer_type, customer_type)
end
```

change customer.update_attribute to customer.update_attributes if you need to update more than one filed using this query.
Thats it.

Comment: @Sraven: Thank you for your help dude.

Comment: Yeah, thank you sravan your answer has worked for me, but there was a minor mistake, as I have to update only one attribute I have to use customer.update_attribute instead of customer.update_attributes, I have edited it in your answer.

Comment: Yes, but `update_attribute` is getting depricated in the latest version of rails, `update_attributes` will also work fine for you.

Comment: update_attributes gave me error for wrong number of arguments :( thats why I changed it and got it worked :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104828/discussion-between-sravan-and-praveen-george).

Comment: Okay.The final working result is important. No problem.Have a good day.

Answer (score 3):

If there are a lot of records, initializing Active Record objects, in a loop is not so efficient. In that case, you can use [ActiveRecord/Relation#update_all](http://ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all)

```
Customer
  .where(customer_type: ["Sale","Lease","Trail"])
  .update_all("customer_type = UCASE(customer_type)")
```

This is for MySql. For Oracle, Postgresql and Sql Server, use `UPPER(column_name)`

Comment: Glad to see that it is an optimised one to use with a large number of record, BTW how to use it in my code simply update my index code with this query at the beginning ?.

Comment: I am using PL Sql in my production

Comment: Yes, this is a Rails method, you can use it in your controller action

Comment: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function ucase(character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "customers" SET customer_type = UCASE(customer_type) WHERE ...

Comment: You seem to have a typo here, it's UPCASE not UCASE

Comment: @tobmatth, The mysql function is indeed `UCASE`. The OP hasn't specified which db he is using.

Answer (score 2):

```
@customers = Customer.where(customer_type: ["Sale","Lease","Trail"])

@customers.each do |customer|
  customer.update_attribute(:customer_type, customer.customer_type.map(&:upcase))
end
```

After retrieving the customers with the expected customer type, we loop through all of them and update their attribute to the uppercase version of all the strings in their `customer_type` array. You don't need to do a check for if the `count > 0` because it won't loop if there are no items in the `@customers` collection.

`customer.customer_type.map(&:upcase)` loops through each of the strings in the customer's `customer_type` array and applies the [`upcase`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-upcase) method to it.

Comment: Thank you for your help dude, lemme try it out :)

Comment: Error: undefined method `map' for "Sale":String

Comment: So the `customer_type` field isn't an array?

Comment: customer_type is a column in customer table with type text

Comment: So are you reading it in as a YAML array by including `serialize :customer_type` in your `Customer` model? If so, this should work, but it seems like you might not be doing that. Anyway, try `customer.customer_type.upcase` instead.